# Missing Authentication Token Error in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I have created a "POST" method API, The lambda function is working properly, I tested the API with Postman, its working there as well. I tested the API in console, it was working fine there too, but when I am invoking the URL, it errors out with `Missing Authentication Token`.

There are no authorization set on the "POST" Method.

Please help. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndnV6.png).

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying that `API Gateway` has extremely poor error messages.

Generally speaking, this is caused by hitting an `API Gateway` endpoint with the wrong `HTTP` method. For example, hitting a `POST` endpoint with a `GET` request.

Are you sure you're using the correct `HTTP` method when you hit the endpoint?